# Cluster-robust error for pearson correlation

Tags: correlation, confidence-interval, clustered-standard-errors

How can I get cluster-robust errors (for generating confidence intervals) on a Pearson correlation coefficient?

I know that I can generate cluster-robust errors for a coefficient in a linear model.  And I know that square-root of the r-squared in the linear model is equivalent to the Pearson correlation.  But I don't know how to get an appropriate standard error on the Pearson correlation.

Note: [this is how i'm accounting for cluster-robust errors](https://www.r-bloggers.com/easy-clustered-standard-errors-in-r/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard error alone cannot be used to generate a confidence interval for a Pearson correlation coefficient.  One way to generate confidence intervals is to do a 'percentile bootstrap' (see [here](http://psycnet.apa.org/psycinfo/1996-97140-000)).  Instead of bootstrapping a standard error, use the bootstrap process to generate a distribution of correlation coefficients.  Then, identify the bounds the inner (eg) 95% of the data to generate a (eg) 95% confidence interval.

To account for clustered data, use a clustered bootstrap:  instead of sampling-with-replacement N individuals for each bootstrap estimate, sample entire clusters.  (see [a practitioners guide to cluster robust inference](http://unionstats.gsu.edu/9220/Camerer-Miller_Clustering_JHR_2015.pdf))